# How to fix iOS 13 beta app crash upon opening the app?

Tags: ios, swift, ios12, ios13

My iOS App in App Store works well on iOS 12, and I tried installing it on my development device with iOS 13 Developer Beta 2, but it crashes on launch. It's impossible to get the crash data using crashlytics as it crashes as soon as it launches.

I tried on Xcode 11 Beta 2, but unfortunately some pre compiled framework (Swift 5.0) doesn't allow me to run on Xcode 11. I managed to get a crash report once using crashlytics, posted below.

```
# Version: 1.58 (1)
   # Bundle Identifier: ------
   # Issue ID: db3066baxxxxxxxeb956f1be
   # Session ID: 013965e31e2d40xxxxxxxx_v2
   # Date: 2019-06-20T08:18:00Z
   # OS Version: 13.0.0 (17A5508m)
   # Device: iPhone XR
   # RAM Free: 3%
   # Disk Free: 9.2%

   #0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
    0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1af2e6f04 __pthread_kill + 8
    1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1af4bec20 pthread_kill + 224
    2  (Missing)                      0x721e0e01af366c00 (Missing)
    3  (Missing)                      0x0 (Missing)
    4  (Missing)                      0xe26c301cfe8a500 (Missing)
    5  (Missing)                      0x0 (Missing)
    6  (Missing)                      0x19607b81cfedc900 (Missing)
    7  (Missing)                      0x4c0f0501048ed400 (Missing)
    8  Libra                          0x104c77988 thunk for @escaping          @callee_guaranteed () -> () (<compiler-generated>)
    9  libdispatch.dylib              0x1af482114 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    10 (Missing)                      0x0 (Missing)
    11 (Missing)                      0x0 (Missing)
    12 (Missing)                      0x574aff81af494800 (Missing)
    13 (Missing)                      0x0 (Missing)
    14 (Missing)                      0x0 (Missing)
    15 (Missing)                      0x502dbc81aec0ec00 (Missing)
    16 (Missing)                      0x3d78bc81aec0e000 (Missing)
    17 (Missing)                      0x0 (Missing)
    18 (Missing)                      0x0 (Missing)
    19 (Missing)                      0x0 (Missing)
    20 libdyld.dylib                  0x1af178964 start + 4
```

This is the error in Crashlytics Dashboard

```
<compiler-generated> line 0
thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> ()
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the Crash by myself after many Sleepless nights.

Seems like this has been the issue in some of the controllers where I casted the UISearchbar subview to customise the UITextField

```
if let searchTextField:UITextField = self.searchView.subviews[0].subviews.last{}
```

So if you come across this issue on iOS 13, Please remove the customisation.

Comment: I figured out searchbar.searchTextField works on ios 13 but not working on ios 12 or lower as it returns nil. Any other soultions for customizing textfields that works on all versions?

Comment: No Idea, But Guess Apple removed all the hacks that are used for customizing that are unethical. But you could use a condition that applies the customisation for iOS 12 and iOS 13

if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    // iOS 13 specific stuff here
} else {
    // non iOS 12 stuff here
}

Comment: Did you find that running the build from App Store or Testflight that it crashed, however, it runs fine on iOS 13+ when ran from Xcode? This is my case now, trying to confirm.

Comment: It happened both on testflight and App store and as well as Xcode when the 13.0 was first released. Haven't tested out that now yet. I deleted those customisations, however.